# AngularJS scope change in one place should change in another, how can this be achieved?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Description:

I have a modal where users can view their profile picture & upload a new one.  This profile picture is shown in the navigation as well (next to their name).

The current process goes like this:

1. User goes to modal
2. User doesn't have photo, shows default stock avatar.  User does, shows theirs
3. User uploads new photo, HTTP response returns the `src` attribute
4. Controller updates scope and sets `$scope.photo` equal to the response

Right now this works perfectly fine as it should.  However, I have the profile photo in the layout view in the side navigation as well which is under command of another controller.

The scope variable is the same name and the HTML is the same, and they are set by the same service.  But, the scope is set from different controllers.

Here is the code for the modal controller:

```
Files.profile_photo()
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.photo = data;
    })

$scope.onFileSelect = function($files) {
    var path = $scope.file_name;
    console.log(path);

    for(var i = 0; i < $files.length; i++) {
        var file = $files[i];

        $scope.upload = $upload.upload({
            url: '/smart2/api/files/profile',
            file: file
        }).success(function(data) {
            $scope.photo = data;
        });
    }
}
```

And then in my controller for my side navigation where the photo also needs to be updated, I call the service `Files` and the function `profile_photo` and do the exact same thing to set the photo when the pages loads.

How can I also update it when it's changed from the modal?  I can't do `$scope.onFileSelect` because that's in the modal inside of another controller.

I need to somehow notify Angular that the photo has been changed and update it in another controller.

What are my options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can handle this with broadcasting an event that the photo changed. I would store the photo in the service, not in the controller, and raise broadcast event when changed. In the controller I would listen to this event to update the image.

```
angular.factory('photo', function($rootScope) {
    var photo =  {};

    var setPhoto = function (p) {
        photo = p;
        $rootScope.$broadcast('photoChanged', p);
    };

    var service = {};
    service.setPhoto = setPhoto;
    return service;
});

angular.controller('photoController', function($rootScope, $scope, photo) {
    $scope.photo = {};
    $rootScope.$on('photoChanged', function(p) {
        $scope.photo = p;
    });

    $scope.changePhoto = function(p) {
        photo.setPhoto(p);
    };
});
```